# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Eco_Bank_Helper_Data' not found in /home/naijaga1/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am facing problem in my magento admin : Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Eco_Bank_Helper_Data' not found in /home/naijaga1/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Please help me by writing solution

**EDIT code:**

```
public static function helper($name) { 
   $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name; 

   if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
      $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);                   
      self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass); 
   } 

return self::registry($registryKey); 
}
```

thanks

Comment: And what's your line 546 ?...

Comment: public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }

Comment: Somewhere you are calling Mage::helper method with wrong name or may be helper class doesn't exists in your bank module.